# Connected component of a graph [Diestel's book]

Tags: graph-theory

[image]

That is an excerpt from Diestel's book. He says that "clearly, the components are induced subgraphs".

But if we look at the graph with vertices $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ with black bold edges we see that actually this is not an induced subgraph, right? If its induced then it should contain an edge joining vertices $1$ and $3$.

Correct me if I am wrong.

**EDIT:** R. Diestel mentions that the following properties are easy to prove. But I guess that they are not so trivial as he says.

1. Components are induced subgraphs.

*Proof:* Suppose that $G'=(V',E')$ is a component of $G$ and it is not an induced subgraph. Then $\exists x,y\in V'$ with $xy\in E$ but $xy\notin E'$. Then the graph $G''=(V',E'\cup xy)$ contains $G'$ as a proper subgraph and $G''$ is connected, which contradicts to maximality of $G'$. Hence $G'$ is induced subgraph.

2. Vertex sets of components partition $V$.

**Proof:** Suppose $G'$ and $G''$ are components of $G$. Then I want to show that $V' \sqcup V''=V$. Since $G'$ and $G''$ are subgraphs then $V'\cup V''\subset V$. One can show that actually $V'\sqcup V''\subseteq V$. How to show that the converse inclusion also holds?

3. Empty graph has no components.

This part seems meaningless and I do not know how to prove it.

Comment: The bolded edges are spanning trees in the three components; the components themselves are the piece on the left with $5$ vertices and $6$ edges, the isolated vertex in the middle, and the copy of $K_5$ on the right (with the labelled vertices). They include all of their edges, not just those in the spanning trees.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, Sorry but I do not know the notion of a tree since it comes after the chapter which I am reading right now. BTW sorry but I did not get your comment at all.

Comment: If you don’t know what a spanning tree is, simply ignore the distinction between boldface and plain edges. You should, however, have been able to understand my description of the components.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, Dear Prof. Scott! I think that I understood what you said. I edited my question. Can you take a look at the edit and help me, please. I'll appreciate your help!

Comment: Your first proof is fine. You’re having trouble with the second because you’ve assumed that $G$ has only two components. This need not be true; if $G$ has $n$ vertices, $G$ can have anywhere from $1$ to $n$ components, depending on what edges it has. See if allowing for more than two components lets you prove the opposite inclusion.

Answer (score 3):

The induced subgraph with vertices 1,2,3,4,5 contains both the bold and the thin edges. This subgraph is one of the connected components of the graph. The graph with just the bold edges is a spanning tree of this connected component of the graph. Distel is explaining multiple concepts in a single picture.

Comment: The induced subgraph with vertices 1,2,3,4,5 is actually $K^5$, right?

Comment: I don't know the notion of tree. It comes after this section so I do not want to go further.

Comment: @ZFR Don't worry about the word "tree" for now. In the caption of the figure you provided you'll notice the words "minimal spanning connected subgraph" are used. The bold edges signify such minimal subgraphs.